# Sharepoint Current User Filter Web Part - what about for a selected user?

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts

The Sharepoint 2010 "Current User Filter" Web Part allows List Web Parts that have been added to the page to be filtered so they will only display data for the current user.

I like this functionality of the out of the box Web Part but I want to know how to extend it.

What can I use to filter list web parts on the page to display on data relevant for a selected user?

I would like it to default to current user but I want to be able to select a person from Active Directory to change the filter to display that persons info.

How should I go about this?  The other filter web parts don't seem to allow person lookups.  Any suggestions on how I can get this functionality another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can develop a simple filter web part yourself to achieve this functionality. That web part will contain a people picker field and will pass the value to the connected web part.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457205(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link.  Looks like just what I'm after